# Send traces to DataDog agentless with SpringBoot3 micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, datadog, micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I wish to send **traces** to DataDog using the latest SpringBoot 3 and micrometer.
DataDog propose a way to use a "DataDog Agent" to help the process.
However, I wish to send traces without the agent (which is possible with many other trace aggregation systems)

To achieve sending trace to DataDog without the agent, I am using this code:

```
import io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.http.trace.OtlpHttpSpanExporter;


    @Bean
    public SpanExporter spanExporter() {
        return OtlpHttpSpanExporter.builder().setEndpoint("https://us5.datadoghq.com/api/v0.3/traces").addHeader("apiKeySecretArn", "abc").build();
    }
```

And the `micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel`

With this, I would expect the trace to go to DataDog.

Unfortunately, it is not.

Just to avoid confusion, the same code is working with Grafana Cloud, and Zipkin server, etc

```
    @Bean
    public SpanExporter spanExporter() {
        return OtlpHttpSpanExporter.builder().setEndpoint("https://tempo-prod-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net:443").addHeader("Authorization", "Basic abc").build();
    }
```

May I ask what is the correct URL and authentication mechanism to send traces to DataDog without agent?

Answer (score 0):

Direct OTLP ingest is not currently supported. To send traces via OTLP you need send them via the Datadog Agent or [OTel Exporter](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/opentelemetry/#datadog-exporter).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the "agent" (as in "collector") in the answer is not the same as the datadog jvm agent (just to avoid confusion). Also, here's the Datadog docs about the OTLP support: https://docs.datadoghq.com/opentelemetry/interoperability/otlp_ingest_in_the_agent/